# Area 51 Discussion Zone doesn't think I have an account on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, ios-app

When trying to vote or comment on a question on Area 51 Discussion Zone via the mobile app, I am told...

[image]

This is a mystery. I have an account on Area 51 and have participated both there and in the Discussion Zone.

Comment: How did you get to Area 51 in the app?

Comment: @Brian I had an inbox notification about Area 51 activity. It took me to Area 51 in the app, but clicking subsequent Area 51 links took me to the in-app mobile browser.

Comment: Proposed question notification took me to safari, is this happening consistently on discussion questions?

Comment: @Brian It has happened with comments on all my DZ posts. Nothing else so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in the latest beta build.  And by fixed I mean it will open Area 51 notifications in Safari now.

The problem is that some parts of the API support Area 51 and some don't.  Importantly `/sites` doesn't which is why we can't go to the question list (and if we could, what would we show?), and `/me/associated` doesn't which means we can't verify site membership.

The second is why you got the error message.  Because we can't verify membership, the best we could offer is a crippled experience where you could read the question but any further interaction sends you to Safari.  Instead we'll just go there directly.